# Does C++Builder work with MSAccess .accdb files?

Tags: database, c++builder, interbase, c++builder-10.3-rio

I am using C++ Builder 10.3. My last version was C++Builder 5 from 20 years ago.

My question comes about because I am totally new to this compiler and the Embarcadero blog sites are now 3rd party and not real usable.

Is it possible to access an MS Access `.accdb` database with the Interbase tools, or something else that comes standard with this compiler?  My old version pre-dates `.accdb`.

Answer (score 0):

[FireDAC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireDAC), which is Embarcadero's latest Database framework, supports connecting to MSAccess databases.

See [Connect to Microsoft Access Database (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connect_to_Microsoft_Access_Database_(FireDAC)) in Embarcadero's DocWiki.

Comment: I started to look at the Wiki you mentioned. Do you know if the descriptions for FireDAC are all in Delphi Pascal? I am hoping to see some written for C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to MS Access database using ADO (dbGo) components. I am not sure if FireDAC is now supported on all editions of C++ Builder (previously, it was not the case). In case of ADO you would create a connection string that uses Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider for `.accdb` database files, or Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider for older `.mdb` files.